# php post ignores manual typed value in google autocomplete form

Tags: php, post, autocomplete

I have the basic location autocomplete fields in an edit form

```
<input type="text" name="street" id="test" placeholder="Locatie" class="form-control" data-class="places" value="<?php echo $userinfo->volunteer_location; ?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="locality" id="locality" placeholder="City" class="form-control" />
<input type="hidden" name="administrative_area_level_1" id="administrative_area_level_1" placeholder="Provincie"/>
<input type="hidden" name="administrative_area_level_2" id="administrative_area_level_2" placeholder="Stad" />
<input type="hidden" name="latitude" id="latitude" placeholder="latitude" />
<input type="hidden" name="longitude" id="longitude" placeholder="longitude" />
```

Whenever i start typing and i select one of the dropdowned options
this value will be send to the controller and saved to the database.

This works fine.

Now whenever i just manually type a place in text field and i try to save this
it seems that the value gets completly ignored and will not be saved in the database.

```
$userdata->location = $this->input->post('test');
```

in scenario 1 this line will contain the autocompleted value
in scenario 2 this post value is non existing or empty?

How can i make sure that people can give in free text as well instead of only working when you select an autocompleted value?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your `<input>` `name` attribute is "street", not "test". Presumably, you should always be using `$this->input->post('street')`

Answer (score -3):

try putting autocomplete="off" for your input attribute